# Proportional aggregation of census data between layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, aggregation

Not sure if anyone here remembers the little program called "AtlasGIS"? Well its been discontinued years ago which is a pity, but it had a function where one could proportionally aggregate for example population data from enumeration areas up to larger polygons (essentially giving you the sum of population of all the enumeration areas that falls into each larger polygon.

The neat thing was that if an enumeration area only partially fell into the larger polygon, AtlasGIS would calculate the % population that fell inside the larger target polygon.   But I can't find such a process elsewhere.

Can anyone help?